# How do I claim the November airdrop using Ledger Nano S?

Tags: beginners

The claim form for the November airdrop asks for a private key but I do not have that available as it stored within my Ledger Nano S. The box for logging in with a Ledger Nano S remains greyed out. I believe the last date to claim is 22nd December 2019. I look forward to your early reply.

Answer (score 1):

That is a scam link. Please do not interface with that website. The only ongoing distribution is through https://keybase.io/a/i/r/d/r/o/p/spacedrop2019 - **anything else is a scam**.

Comment: I would never give up my private keys to anyone however I do appreciate the quick feedback that this is a scam site.

In the last few months I have received 4 airdrops of XLM. For the first 3 the websites no longer exist. For the 4th airdrop they gave the web address which - rightly so - the moderator has crossed out.
I assume all four airdrops were scams but I now own more XLM.

I am hoping the scammers send me more.

I appreciate your help. I have signed up for the Keybase airdrop.

Mark